# Short story about teenagers who have a friend who has an accident which causes brain damage but seems really happy after

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think it was in a book of short stories, possibly by Douglas Coupland. The teenagers start trying to brain damage themselves just to be happy and escape the stresses of teenage life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: And are there any fantasy or sci-fi aspects to it?

Comment: This rings a bell, though I don't think it was by Douglas Coupland and I don't think it's science fiction. Were the teenagers using oxygen deprivation to cause the brain damage?

Comment: Some bits of it reminds me of Flatliners...